# Is a single big read/write request to the operating system less expensive than multiple small read/write requests?

Tags: linux, kernel, system-calls

According to the official documentation, one of the reasons why Java implements Buffered Streams is

> Most of the examples we've seen so far use unbuffered I/O. This means each read or write request is handled directly by the underlying OS. This can make a program much less efficient, since each such request often triggers disk access, network activity, or some other operation that is relatively expensive.

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/buffers.html

Is a single big read/write request on Linux really expensive compared to multiple small read/write requests ? How efficient is the former compared to the latter ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the text there refers to buffering within the application. That's commonly done by even the C library. For example, if you call `getchar()`, the C library doesn't ask the OS for a single byte, but reads a full block (a couple of kilobytes, usually), so that the next `getchar()` doesn't need to make a system call. Returning data from buffer within the process is much faster than a system call that necessarily involves a switch from user mode to kernel mode.

> Is a single big read/write request on Linux really expensive compared to multiple small read/write requests?

A big request is probably cheaper since it saves on the overhead of multiple small ones. But where did you get this idea from? I can't see the linked document mention either big or small requests?

Comment: "For example, if you call getchar(), the C library doesn't ask the OS for a single byte, but reads a full block (a couple of kilobytes, usually), so that the next getchar() doesn't need to make a system call." This is what I want to understand. Why did C/Java do this ? What would be the difference between making a system call for each char vs a small number of system calls that load chunks of chars in the memory. My big vs small requests question was based on this. I think I should have worded it in a different way. Thank you for your response :)

Comment: @vadasambar, first paragraph, last sentence: _"Returning data from buffer within the process is much faster than a system call that necessarily involves a switch from user mode to kernel mode."_

Answer (score 0):

As disk blocks will generally be cached by the OS, most short reads and writes will not need to access the device directly. In addition, the OS generally notices when you read two consecutive blocks, and issues a preemptive read-ahead on the next block, so it is already cached when you want it.

However, there is a significant additional performance issue that comes into play. When your process makes a system call, it yields the CPU to any other process that is ready to run. After your syscall is satisfied, your process just goes in a scheduler queue and awaits its turn to run. If there are CPU-bound processes in the mix, they will use their maximum time slice each time they are scheduled, and your process gets hung up behind that for every access.